# jquery animate, set interval and inactive window issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this weird issue that i am hitting, i have a slide show in which set interval fires up jquery animate method. all works great.

Until i switch tabs. If i switch back to tab with slideshow in some time, all of the sudden animation is fired repeatedly, with out any inteval in place. Like it is playing catch up.

I kind of figured that it has something to do with RequestAnimationFrame and jQuery's animate method. And how animation rendering is suppressed while tab is inactive. While interval is kept on firing up every so often, even when window is inactive.

Could any one elaborate more on this, would much appreciate it.

Here is the core code that does that:

```
function animate(setCurrent){
    animationDistance = opt.cSlideWidth * (opt.cCurrentSlide - 1);
    carousel.animate({left: '-' + animationDistance}, opt.cTransitionSpeed});
}
opt.cSetUpIntervalMethod = function(action){
    if (action === 'start') {
        clearInterval(opt.cSlideTimer);
        opt.cSlideTimer = setInterval(function(){animate();},opt.cSlideDelay);
    }
}
opt.cSetUpIntervalMethod('start');
```

Comment: Weird; I was going to fire up a question like this later today, and just happened to stumble across yours. Exact same issue. Will update my instance of jQuery to see if it helps. ;-)

Comment: i updated it to 1.7, and all good. You should be fine once you update this. Let me guess you used boilerplate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug in older versions of JQuery which has since been fixed as of 1.6.3. Update your version.

> "We had high hopes for the browser’s requestAnimationFrame API when we
>   added support into version 1.6. However, one of the highest-volume
>   complaints we’ve received since then relates to the way
>   requestAnimationFrame acts when a tab is not visible. All the
>   animations initiated when the tab is invisible “stack” and are not
>   executed until the tab is brought back into focus. Then they all
>   animate at warp speed! We’ve removed support for this API (which has
>   no impact on the way you call jQuery’s animation features) and plan to
>   incorporate it into a future version of jQuery."

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/01/jquery-1-6-3-released/

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and Firefox slow down interval timers when a page goes to the background to preserve CPU and battery.  When you bring it back to the foreground, they try to "make up" for some of the lost timers.  See [this post in the Chromium blog](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-dev/browse_thread/thread/ff827011f2d1f0f6/e67586a804d173f0) for a brief description of what they implemented.

The best way to solve the issue is to stop your animation when your window goes out of view and start it again when it comes back into view.

Chrome has an [experimental API](http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility.html) for doing just this.  If that is not available, fallback methods involve using focus detection to see if focus is anywhere in your window.

Comment: take a look at @AlienWebguy's post.

Comment: but thank you for your input. Even though set interval is slowed down, animation execution is still fired up, but because of the animation API, and as i found out from @AlienWebguy's post, animations played back only when tab is active.

Comment: You will still have issues if you're trying to do anything that is timer related when the page goes into the background because timers are throttled in the background.

Answer (score 1):

do not use setinterval() for animations that can lose focus.  you accomplish the same effect with [.delay(milliseconds)](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and a recursive javascript method call.